# Why does Sentinel limit a character to attacking only creatures that target characters without Sentinel?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

The third bullet of the sentinel feat text reads:

> When a creature makes an attack
>   against a target other than you (and that target doesn't
>   have this feat), you can use your reaction to make a
>   melee weapon attack against the attacking creature.

This reads to me as saying if both I and the target of the original attack have sentinel, then I can't take the reaction attack.  Is this correct?  If so, does anyone have insight into why?

I could maybe understand if the text is actually in error and meant to say "and the attacking creature doesn't have this feat," but it pretty clearly doesn't actually say that.

Comment: Please do not answer in comments. Such comments have been removed per [Should users refrain from...?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/23970)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because designer reasons are off-topic or if I'm misunderstanding the querent it is opinion based either way -from review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You read the text correctly

As it is written you can't make an Opportunity Attack against a creature in your melee range targeting a creature other than you if that target has the Sentinel feat.

I couldn't find any information about why this is the case, but I would imagine that it's supposed to prevent your group of Sentinel PCs from surrounding an enemy and all trigger an Opportunity Attack at the same time if that enemy attacks one of the group.

In response to the comment: note that you can still do this by surrounding your enemy and provoking him to attack the one PC that does *not* have the Sentinel feat. If he attacks any target with the feat nobody will get the chance for a Sentinel Opportunity Attack, but if he targets the one target without the feat everyone else around your enemy with the feat can attack. Just make sure that the one without the feat is definitely looking like he's closest to death, be prepared for an enemy doing this mistake once, not twice, and keep an eye out for enemies escaping, as they will surely tell their boss of this tactic. This makes it more difficult for this trick to work, which I think is the intention of the extra bit the OP asked about.

Comment: You can still do the surround + mass opportunity attack provided the attacker attacks the one PC that doesn't have this feat ("Oh no, evil monster, please don't attack me, I'm just a squishy wizard!").

Comment: I suppose that might be it, but it seems a little inelegant.  Pile of characters with polearms and sentinel except one who happens to get hit: poke party.  Give that one guy sentinel: nothing.

Comment: @nwp But that is more situational. If there is a nearly-dead Fighter and a full-health Wizard you already attacked, but because of Blur and Shield you couldn't hit him you would choose the one you can kill, thereby not triggering the Opportunity mob surrounding you. Just because you say "I am a Wizard" doesn't necessarily mean you get hit. But yeah, surrounding the enemy and getting him to attack your weakest ally is a possibility.