# Why does the Sentinel Feat include this condition?

Tags: dnd-5e

In D&D 5e, the last part of the Sentinel feat contains this text:

> When a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a target other than you **(and that target doesn't have this feat)**, you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against the attacking creature

1. **Thematically**, why shouldn't you get the opportunity attack if the target has Sentinel? I can't think of any flavor/narrative reasons why your ally having an ability would prevent you from using your own ability.
2. If that clause was included strictly to prohibit combos among fellow sentinels, **is there an official source that says as much?**

**EDIT:** This is not a duplicate. The linked answer only clarifies that Sentinel says what it says. It does not say why, nor give any sources that describe the reason for this design decision.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Why does Sentinel limit a character to attacking only creatures that target characters without Sentinel?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107238)

Comment: Please know that questions asking for [design intent](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/52137) are now off-topic (and the dupe target has now been closed for that reason). We may still be able to help you though, why are you digging for design statements? If you're concerned with the implications for making a change/house rule to this change you should be able to ask about that and have it answered.

Comment: @Someone_Evil The primary focus of the question was indeed design intent, and mostly just for my own curiosity. Thank you for the link to the Meta post, though